# how to configure emacs to start in a directory (windows)

Tags: windows, emacs

I am running emacs 25.1 under Windows.  It is a standalone binary, not running under cygwin

I have a .emacs file that works on both windows and linux.  On Windows, however, the command:

(cd "c:/Users/xxx/git")

does not start emacs in that directory.  The command works, because if I evaluate the buffer, it does go to that directory.  It is as though something else is executing AFTER my script causing emacs to default to the stupid windows default, wherever the code is.

Any workaround to make emacs start in my desired directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Windows shortcut to the Emacs executable, and use that to start Emacs. Create the shortcut by right-clicking the file `runemacs.exe` in folder `bin` and choosing **Create shortcut**.

Then fill out the **Properties** in the **Shortcut** tab:

Field **Target** has the command for starting Emacs: the location and name of the binary (executable) followed by whatever options you want and any file or directory that you want to start editing.

Field **Start in** has the directory that I want Emacs to start in.

For example:

- **Target:** `D:\Emacs-25.1\bin\runemacs.exe --debug-init "d:\usr\some-user-name\some-directory"`
- **Start in:** `d:\usr\some-user-name\some-directory`

Then just double-click your shortcut to start Emacs. Or single-click it, if you pin it to the Task Bar.

You can create as many such shortcuts as you want, either to the same Emacs executable (e.g. with different options or startup directories) or to different executables (e.g. different Emacs releases).

Comment: I would take this if I had to, but do you have any idea why that would happen after the init file runs?  The directory should start being what I specify, and the script should be capable of overriding once emacs is running.  And when I manually execute the script after startup (eval-current-buffer) it works.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. After the init file runs, you are in the `Start in` directory. If you also provide it as the "file" to visit then you are even in it in Dired. You can change the current directory anytime in Emacs - see command `cd` and variable `default-directory`. See the Emacs manual, node [File Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Names.html).

Comment: so the start in directory is set *after* .emacs is run?  The same script in Unix would correctly set the directory to the desired one. .emacs is run after the process is started (AFAIK)

Comment: No, AFAIK, a Windows Shortcut `Start in` means run the executable in that directory, i.e., *it is current **before** the executable starts*. I'm no Windows expert, but I assume that is the whole point of `Start in`. It is *also* the case that, *unless* the command options (including loading any Lisp file that you load via the command line) or your init-file code (including libraries it loads) *change* the `default-directory`, the `Start in` directory is still current *after* startup. You can specify any directory for Emacs to visit, and that does not change the directory of `Start in`.

Comment: Apparently I am not understanding your question fully. I'd suggest that you simply *try it*. `Start in` determines where Windows program `runemacs.exe` starts. But other command options and code that you tell Emacs to load can change the current directory (`default-directory`). If no command option and none of the code you load changes it then `default-directory` after your init file is processed remains the directory of `Start in`. This is all explained in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html), I believe.

Comment: See also the Emac manual, node [Emacs Invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Invocation.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `emacs-startup-hook`, which runs after processing the commandline and init.el.

```
(defun jpk/emacs-startup-hook ()
  (cd "/some/path"))
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook #'jpk/emacs-startup-hook)
```

If that doesn't work, some package is setting the CWD, and you'll have to track it down.